# Disable Webmin when not in use?

Tags: solaris, webmin

My web server has "webmin" web based admin console installed and accessible on port 10000. Typically I do not use it except for adding a new domain name (mysite.com, etc). Since that is rare, do you recommended I disable port 10000 for added security?

I am running recent version of Solaris. If you do recommend it; do I use IP Tables to shut off the port? Also, in the future I can simply renable the port when I need it again?

Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just stop the Webmin service when not in use and start it again when you plan to use it.

Comment: Seems logical enough, I am getting more comfortable with Solaris each day. Ill search for stopping the service. Is the port still vulnerable if i shut down service? Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: If the service is shut down there will be nothing listening on the port (unless you have something else using it) and, therefore, nothing to be vulnerable.

Comment: Stop xinet ou xinetd service